# Can i use the same method in two activities?

Tags: java, android

I am hiding the navigation bar in one activity and works fine.

**My question is if there is any way to call this method in another activity or should i just copy and paste it twice?**

```
public void hideNavigationBar() {
int currentApiVersion;
currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

// This work only for android 4.4+
if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
{

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

    // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
    // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
    // show up and won't hide
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                {
                    if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                    {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
}
}
```

I tried calling the same method in another activity by creating an instance of it

```
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainAcitivity();
 mainAcitvity.hideNavigationBar();
```

, but it throws

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: it's a public method, so yes, that 's possible, as long as you do it correctly

Comment: `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainAcitivity()` Thats a disaster .. You never create an object of an Activity .. Read Docs ..

Comment: move the method to a different class (not a concrete activity) and use that class in both activities

Comment: Create a `BaseActivity` class that extends `AppCompatActivity` and then have each your activity extend that one. All shared functionality should go into `BaseActivity`.

Comment: Or you can do what @TimCastelijns said

Comment: also you don't need to the kitkat check. Unless your target audience lives in caves

Comment: Please move hideNavigationBar() method to Utils class and Create instance of Utils class in your activity to use its method

Answer (score 6):

Create `BaseActivity()` and extend your other `Activity` with `BaseActivity`. And place your common method in `BaseActivity`. Then you can call from any `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to creating a base class:

```
public static void hideNavigationBar(View decorView) {

    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    if(SDK_INT >= KITKAT) {
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With usage (inside any Activity):

`hideNavigationBar(getWindow().getDecorView());`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, creating a parent activity class extending Activity.java or AppcompatActivity.java class will definitely help you.

Later this parent activity can be extended in both of your activities.

```
class ParentActivity extends Activity{
   public void yourMethod(){
  }
}
//Later
class FirstActivity extends ParentActivity {

}
class SecondActivity extends ParentActivity {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create the parent activity.

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {
     public void yourMethod() {
     //implement your method here
     }
}
```

After that you only have to create the activities just like that:

```
class Activity1 extends ParentActivity {
//call the override method
}
class Activity2 extends ParentActivity {
//call the override method
}
```

If you have a Fragment you can solve this problem in the same way